# React useStyles not applying styles

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to create an E-Commerce platform in React JS. I am following tutorials from Youtube. I don't know whats the problem but the styles from the styles components are not applying properly, cross-checked the code with the tutor's code several code but was unable to figure out as what is the issue. **Can anybody spot the issue?**

Products.jsx Component

```
import React from 'react'
import {Card, CardMedia, CardContent, CardActions, Typography} from '@material-ui/core'
import { IconButton } from '@material-ui/core'
import { AddShoppingCart} from '@material-ui/icons'
import useStyles from './styles'

const Product = ({product}) => {

    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
        <Card className={classes.root}>
            <CardMedia className={classes.media} image={product.image} title={product.name} />
            <CardContent>
                <div className={classes.CardContent}>
                    <Typography variant="h5" gutterBottom>
                        {product.name}
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography variant="h5">
                        {product.price}
                    </Typography>
                </div>

                <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary">{product.description}</Typography>

                <CardActions disableSpacing className={classes.CardActions}>
                    <IconButton aria-label="Add to Cart">
                        <AddShoppingCart/>
                    </IconButton>
                </CardActions>
            </CardContent>
        </Card>
    )
}

export default Product
```

Styles. js file is here

```
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core";

export default makeStyles(() => ({
    root: {
        maxWidth: "100%"
    },
    media: {
        height: 0,
        paddingTop: '56.25%'
    },
    carrdActions: {
        display: 'flex',
        justifyContent: 'flex-end'
    },
    cardContent: {
        display: 'flex',
        justifyContent: 'space-between'
    }
}))
```

**Any help is appreciated!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This must be `classes.carrdActions`:

```
           <CardActions disableSpacing className={classes.CardActions}>
```

Because you defined it like this:

```
  carrdActions: {
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end'
},
```

Same with `classes.CardContent`

Answer (score 0):

please import makeStyles from this:

```
    import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
     // not
    import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core";
```

I'm sure your problem will be solved;